# jquery how to run function only after updating hidden input value

Tags: jquery

shortcut, try this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/purushagovinda/VJfkx/

---

I have a block of jquery code that I want to get right so that it will set the value of a hidden input element (changed from `value="keywords"` to `value="furniture"`), and **THEN** call a function ("`refresh_itemListerWithSearchResultsReturn();`") which reloads a main div's content from an ajax call to another file - a file which depends on the hidden input's value.

My code now successfully sets the value of the hidden input, and then fires the function, BUT, upon firing, the function still thinks the hidden input value="keywords".  It makes me think I want to do this:

```
$("#myHiddenInput").val('furniture');
```

...but where that line ^^^ has a callback function, and I stick the `refresh_itemListerWithSearchResultsReturn()` function call *inside* the .val() callback.   So, being a relative noob, I look up here:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

... but do not see there how to use `.val();` with a callback function.  The example on that docs page shows `.val()` with a function call, but that function is for determining what the `val()` will use for the value itself, as opposed to firing a callback, like I need.

Any advise for me how to proceed?

---

the code actually looks like this:

```
$("#products_furniture_furnitureType_options > li").each(function() {
 $(this).click(function(e) {
  [snip]
  $("#dp_searchForWhichItemType_listRefresh").val('products');
  $('#bit_products_productType').val('furniture');

  $("#bit_products_productType").val("furniture").change(function(){
    alert("'#bit_products_productType' is changed now 2");
    $.refresh_itemListerWithSearchResultsReturn('itemList', false, false);
  });

  [snip]
 });
});
```

I also tried this:

```
$("#products_furniture_furnitureType_options > li").each(function() {
 $(this).click(function(e) {
  [snip]
  $("#dp_searchForWhichItemType_listRefresh").val('products');
  $('#bit_products_productType').val('furniture');

  $("#bit_products_productType").change(function(){
    alert("'#bit_products_productType' is changed now 2");
    $.refresh_itemListerWithSearchResultsReturn('itemList', false, false);
  });

  [snip]
 });
});
```

...and also tried moving the `$("#bit_products_productType").change(function(){` to before the `$('#bit_products_productType').val('furniture');`...

...but in every case the `alert("'#bit_products_productType' is changed now 2");` does not fire.

this ought to help you guys focus, and be able to help me:
http://jsfiddle.net/purushagovinda/VJfkx/

Comment: Can you show your full code here?

Comment: java-script runs on a single thread. if you fire the reload function on the next line you can be sure that the value is already updated

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve but why don't you pass the new value as a param in your reloadResults function?

Comment: have tried that? is that work for you ?

Comment: passing the new value as a param in my reloadResults function sounds like good sense, but the code is actually pretty long, and I want to see if I can quck fix this rather than re-write so many calls to that function in other places as well.  

Meanwhile when I try Pranay Rana's answer, the `alert("value is changed now");` does not fire.  I don't know why.. yet.

Comment: please see here: this ought to help make this quick and clear:
 http://jsfiddle.net/purushagovinda/VJfkx/

Comment: @Josh , if you answer with your comment, I will accept it.  I found the error in my code that led to my posting this thread, which turns out was easier than I thought.. and not actually needing all the good help offered by responders. But in case anyone responds further, I'll pursue learning about those useful topics/things.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript runs on a single thread. if you fire the `reload function` on the next statement you can be sure that the value is already updated (there is no need for callback functions).

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
$("#myHiddenInput").val("product").change(function(){
  alert("value is changed now");
});
```

check : [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) -  Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Comment: Yes! .change function is the answer

Comment: see my OP, where I added code..  I tried something like you describe here, but the alert does not fire.  (?)

Comment: please see here: this ought to help make this quick and clear:
 http://jsfiddle.net/purushagovinda/VJfkx/

Answer (score 0):

try this code ...

```
 $('#hiddenfieldid').live('change', function() {  
        function1(); 
    });
```

Comment: IIRC, `.live` is for adding handlers for elements that only get added to the DOM afterwards, like from an AJAX request.  right?  In my case the hidden input element is already there in the first place.  Anyway I did try your suggestion just in case it might reveal any clue at all.. but it just behaves the same, i.e. does not fire the function (or `alert()` which I added to inside the `.live('change', function() {` ...

Answer (score 0):

Yu can use [.change](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change) event to do your requirement.

```
$("#myHiddenInput").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: see my OP, where I added code..  I tried something like you describe here, but the alert does not fire.  (?)